# Excel data translation - INDEX, MATCH, OFFSET?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, transform, offset

I'm trying to create a business 'calendar' in a specific format: weeks down the side, categories across the top. I have the data in a flat format but cannot work out how to translate it.

I've tried thinking in terms of INDEX, MATCH, OFFSET etc but can't get my head around it.

Are there any whizzes out there who can help, please? I'm usually quite good at this stuff but perhaps I'm having a mental block.

Basically I'm trying to get from the table on the left to the table on the right. What formula can I use in the yellow cells?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You haven't done me any by not telling me what the alternative is? Am new to this!

Comment: Also, you are not doing yourself any favors with lack of clarity...what is your goal in   the transition? What is the purpose of the letters in table 1?  Also, are you, "...usually quite good..." or, "new to this?"

Comment: New to this website...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter as an array formula in `Q2:U11` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(C2:L6)=0,"",B2:B6))
```

Comment: Thank you - I will try this shortly and let you know. I've not used TRANSPOSE before... intriguing.

Comment: Amazing... I really need to get my head around CSE functions. Very concise and works perfectly - thank you jblood94